# How to loop through an array via an async function inside another async function?

Tags: javascript, async-await

I am trying to call two apis with two async function.The thing is that the second
 async function's api call depends upon the the result of the first async   function.

1. My first async function fetches some data from an api and returns an
   array(users) of objects .
2. The second async function calls another api that takes the `id` property from
   each object of `users` as url parameter.and will returns a status for each
   object and we want to filter only those user that has status `204`.

I know the logic on how to do this but can't implement it in real world.Plus
nested async functions always seems hard to me , here is my attempt :

```js
    const getUsers = async () => {
        const { users } = await axios.get(url);
        return users;
    };

    const getCheckedUsers = async () => {
        const allUsers = await getUsers();
        const promises = allUsers.then(users => {
            users.map(async user => {
                const { status } = await axios.get(another_url_that_takes_`user.id`);
                if (status === "204") {
                    return user;
                }
            });
        });
        const results = await Promise.all(promises);
        return results;
    }
```

First function works fine i tested it separately.It returns the needed array.
But the issue starts when i try to combine first async function with the second
one.

Comment: What's the result of your code  ?

Comment: @YoussefTounoussi result is `unhandled promise rejection`

Comment: So return allUsers and not results and remove this line     const results = await Promise.all(promises);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `async`/`await` there's no need to get lost with Promises since the code just runs line by line:

```js
const getUsers = async () => {
  const { users } = await axios.get(url);
  return users;
};

const getCheckedUsers = async () => {
  const allUsers = await getUsers();
  const results = [];
  for (user of allUsers) {
    const { status } = await axios.get(`another_url_that_takes_${user.id}`);
    if (status === "204") {
      results.push(user);
    }
  }
  return results;
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't it return the `results[]` even before the data is fetched ?

Comment: No, since the `await` inside the `for..of` ensures the synchronous behavior for each iteration.

Comment: Note that the code in this answer runs sequential, whereas the code in OPs question attempts a concurrent approach.

Comment: Seems to be working fine for now . Thanks but i will still try do some more tests with this and will come back if any issue comes up .

Comment: @3limin4t0r this code directly answers the question "how to loop through an array via an async function inside another async function?".

Comment: @ErickPetrucelli I know this answers the question. I simply want to point out the behaviour difference to unaware readers.

Comment: @Rocktim I'm happy it worked. Please don't forget to mark the accepted answer if you think your problem is solved at all.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few issues with your current code.

1. You invoke `.then` on a non promise value (`allUsers.then`). This isn't needed because you already do `const users = await getUsers()` which will set `users` to the resolved value, not a promise.
2. By using `map` and only returning the `user` if `status` equals `"204"`, you will implicitly return `undefined` for users that have a status other then `"204"`. If the intent is to leave out the values completely you can use `filter` on the `users` array.

```
const getUsers = async () => {
    const { users } = await axios.get(url);
    return users;
};

const getStatus = async (user) => {
    const { status } = await axios.get(`another_url_that_takes_${user.id}`);
    return status;
};

const getCheckedUsers = async () => {
    const users = await getUsers();
    const statuses = await Promise.all(users.map(getStatus));
    return users.filter((_, index) => statuses[index] === "204");
};
```

Comment: thanks for the explanation :) I really learned a lot from this.

Comment: This explanation looking like a wowww.